# Storing the functions return values in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can we store some of the functions return value in the array. for example i have a array in `javascript` and i am wanted to store the `function` return value in that array its either `true` or `false`. 
Then after that checking how many occurrences of true or false present in the array.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show your code and your attempts so far. There are multiple ways of storing return values in arrays and there are multiple ways of counting them.

Comment: yes why not? can you be more specific? A fiddle perhaps http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Have you tried storing a function's return value in an array?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I know precisely what you are asking

```
function Foo(i) {
    return i%2 == 0 ? true : false
}

var bar= [];

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    bar.push(Foo(i));
}
```

Will result in an array of the results of Foo(). In this case alternating true/false values;

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = [];

function xyz(){

    ....
    // Whatever definition
    ...

    if(...){
    x.push(true);
    return true;
    }

    else{
    x.push(false);
    return false;
    }

}
```

Now check in `x` the occurrences of `true` of `false`.